# What is the difference between Canvas.SetTop(objFrameworkElement,10); and objFrameworkElement.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty,20)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a question . What is the difference between Canvas.SetTop(objFrameworkElement,10); and objFrameworkElement.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty,20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part you can use either approach interchangeably.  The key difference is that `Canvas.SetTop` uses the specific type `Double` for the value parameter whereas `SetValue` uses `Object`.

Hence using things like `SetTop` is a better practice when you know the property you actually want to set.  You'll get compile time errors when you're passing the wrong type whereas using `SetValue` you won't know of the error until runtime.

Comment: Thanks I think this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the same thing. `Canvas.SetTop` calls `SetValue` on the element. There are sometimes a bit of logic in the SetX methods, like calling `ClearValue` instead of `SetValue` if the specified value is the same as the default value (that's not the case for `Canvas.Top`). So I prefer using the GetX/SetX methods.

Comment: Sorry but in didn't get your answer. I was also knowing that these are same but I was asked a question to explain the difference and I was not able to .So please can you elaborate  your answer. Thank you